# Show parent-child hierarchy with existing values in power bi matrix

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, parent-child

I am trying to display a parent-child hierarchy in a matrix visual, which should display the value for each child and parent without performing a calculation.

The data looks like this

[image: Data]

And the matrix should ultimately (in Power BI visual) have the following structure and values

[image: how the structure of the matrix and values should be]

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks

I tried following the Guide here: https://www.daxpatterns.com/parent-child-hierarchies/
But I keep getting either a calculation for the parent, or the "first value" of the child in the parent level.

Comment: The article you link is basically the solution to your question. I think this question should be more focused as to where you feel the solution linked does not line up with what results you have gotten, and you should give more detail as to what you are getting vs. what you expect.

Comment: I get the same result as in the article, but this is not what I want. In the article, the value of the parent company, is the sum (or som other calculation) of the child companies. This is not what I want. I simply want to display whatever value is connected to each company, no matter how the Parent-child relationship is defined..